# Calculating total in MySQL database and dividing by ten pagination

Tags: java, c++, mysql, pagination

I have code that references MySQL database, it looks like this:

```
<div id="pagination">
    <ul class="page">
        <li class="page"><a href="<c:url value='item?${loop.count${item.id}'/>">${loop.count}</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

the for loop looks like this:

```
<c:forEach var="item" items="${itemItems}" begin="0" end="10" varStatus="loop">
```

This displays a list of numbers for me to use for pagination.
My question is this, how can I change the `${loop.count}</a>` to a number that calculates the total items in a row/table divided by ten?  Right now this is counting the items displayed only in the loop on the page.  I'd like for it to count all items in the row instead of just the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You need to determine the amount of rows you get without MySQL `LIMIT` and `OFFSET`

Two options here:

1. Execute the query a second time without `LIMIT` / `OFFSET`
2. Add `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` to your query:

   SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS ...

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows

In both cases you can get the amount of total rows using `SELECT FOUND_ROWS() AS rows_total`

The decision which option is faster depends on your database structure, query complexity and result data. Give it a try and compare the times.

Calculation of pages, offsets and limits is simple math

pseudoCode

```
numPages = ceil( totalRows / rowsPerPage )
sqlLimit = rowsPerPage
sqlOffset = (currentPage-1) * rowsPerPage
```

Comment: If you were to show me this method with this application it would help a done, but all I need to do is take the value of ${itemItems}   and divide it by ten. When I try ${itemItems}/10 in every way, shape and form.  The output is "(the loop)/10" <-- literally. Riddle me this batman ..   I'm almost certain I could just use an if { (i<${itemItems};i=0;i++)  right??   If this is an option, could u possibly show me a fundamental way of going about this??  Would I have to name a seperate variable for i or could I just instantaniate it within the command??